# Adobe Air Badge Installer not working on Firefox and Safari on OSX Lion

Tags: apache-flex, air

We use a custom Air Install badge to install / launch an Air application directly from the website simillar to

[TweetDeck](http://tweetdeck.com)

This normally handles the install of air if the user doesn't have it already installed.

However, after doing some cross broswer testing, it appears that when a user, (using OSX Lion and Safari or Firefox) tries to click yes when prompted to download the required Air they are unable to click either of the yes or no buttons.

[image: Dialog which user can't click]

**Has anyone experienced this issue or know of any solutions or work arounds?**

I initially thought that it may have had something to do with the positioning so ensured that the z-index in the css was appropriately set but to no avail.

I beleive it may have something to do with the installer itself rather than my implementation as the same thing appears to happen on [TweetDeck](http://tweetdeck.com) too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the issues was due to the version of FlashPlayer that the browser was using.

By upgrading FlashPlayer, the badge functions correctly on Windows, however on OSX there  still seems to be a bug where, if you do not have Adobe Air installed, it will not ask if you want to install the Air runtime and it and will proceed to install the application anyway - resulting in the install failing.

As of writing the latest FlashPlayer version was 11.x

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I've run into this issue before.  The workaround we found was to restructure the html/css so that no ancestor of the badge uses margin: auto.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is there any reasoning as to why this workaround should work? I tried removing any margin: auto properties but to no avail?

Comment: None at all.  I just found that that worked for me.  You might try dropping your badge into an otherwise empty, unstyled html file, just to rule out any html/css-related bugs.